# How do I make sure an image doesn't contain malicious code?

Tags: security, pictures

There's this stunning wallpaper that I'd love to have on my desktop. However, it's from a shady site and I'm worried it might contain some kind of a virus. So, first thing I did was to wipe the metadata with exiftool on a live USB to prevent any buffer overflow. Next, I flipped the image in the hope that it'll "flip" the sequence of the potential malicious code in the image, hopefully rendering it useless. Is there anything else I can do to make sure the image is safe to open?

PS please excuse the dumb question. I've been reading about a bunch of exploits that relied on hidden code in images, hence the paranoia.

Comment: Download to a disposable USB key and scan the key with your Anti Virus.

Comment: @John don't these typically escape antivirus software?

Comment: A good anti virus app should pick up an image containing a virus. You may also wish to scan additionally with Malwarebytes.

Comment: Cat and mouse game, all av databases are 2 weeks behind the latest malware, download it and let is set for 3 weeks, then scan.

Comment: Paranoia is the word. What you did was more than enough to disable any exploit.

Comment: A malicious file does not have valid metadata associated with an image.  In fact I would argue that if it was a malicious file it wouldn’t be a valid image. The entire idea behind the file being malicious is that someone would present something you want, you download something entirely different (the malicious file), and you treat it as the actual file unknowingly.  However, if it’s the actual image you want, it’s not likely to be malicious (most criminals are too lazy to fake legitimate metadata for a file)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a surefire way not to get owned.

As mentioned you can run it through virustotal.com which checks files using at least 50 antiviruses.

Fire up a virtual machine, open the image in IrfanView, save it in any image format (e.g. BMP, JPG, PNG) and copy the result to your host. This will guarantee there's no hidden malware or any "bad" bytes in the image which can be misinterpreted and lead to code execution.

Answer (score 1):

Upload it to https://www.virustotal.com/ for checking.
There are many scanners there to validate the payload.

This is a page where a file can be automatically scanned using many commercial anti-virus scanners.

Info from the VirusTotal site: "Analyze suspicious files and URLs to detect types of malware, automatically share them with the security community."

It is free to use.

Keep in mind that it is not suitable for any personal data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).